# NSTextView: apply paragraph style

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstextview

I'm trying to apply the default paragraph style to a NSTextView but it doesn't seem to work. Any idea?

```
    var paragraphStyle:NSMutableParagraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle();
    paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 100.0;
    paragraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = 100.0;
    WLMainEditor.defaultParagraphStyle = paragraphStyle;
```

Comment: Have you tried attributed string with this code? Code seems good

Comment: Can you upload this part of you code?

Answer (score 1):

I find that it always works best to start with an existing paragraph style and make changes to it. If you don't have one to start with, use `NSParagraphStyle.default()`

```
let paragraphStyle = NSParagraphStyle.default().mutableCopy() as! NSMutableParagraphStyle
paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 100
paragraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = 100
WLMainEditor.defaultParagraphStyle = paragraphStyle
```

Also, at least in this code snippet, the paragraphStyle can (and should be) a `let` instead of a `var` since it's an Objective-C mutable object and not a Swift mutable collection.